# jQuery: Firefox focusout Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, focusout

I've got two input boxes in a div, I want to hide that div on the focusOut of the inputs, but only if both of them do not have focus.

This is a common Firefox problem (some call it adhering to standard), but the document body steals focus between.

#### HTML

---

```
<div id="baz">
   <input type="text" id="foo" name="foo" />
   <input type="text" id="bar" name="bar" />
</div>
```

#### jQuery

---

```
// jQuery Example
jQuery(":input").focusout(function(){
   // Don't do anything if one of the input boxes has focus
   if( jQuery(":input").is( jQuery(document.activeElement) ){ return; }

   // Hide the container if one of the inputs loose focus
   jQuery(this).parents("div").css("display","none");
}
```

Though *this is a common bug*, I forget how I solved it in the past.  I think it had something to do with setting a timeout, or doing a screen refresh, before checking for the `activeElement`.

---

#### [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/mvW3B/)

#### [jsFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/mvW3B/1/) (FF4 Same Problem)

Comment: small tip: Use `hide()` in place of `css('display', 'none')`

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @Jared: I usually would, but I was at work and leaving for the day.  @namuol: I agree, I was trying to think of an example where some function is called based on the condition of the event, display was just what came to mind `hide()` would be better; I'm still not an advocate of pure jQueryism, I like to stick to native JavaScript, but am coming around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nRENJ/)

```
jQuery(":input").focusout(function(){
    var elem = jQuery(this).parent("div");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
            // Don't do anything if one of the input boxes has focus
            if( jQuery(":input").is( jQuery(document.activeElement) )){ return; }

            // Hide the container if one of the inputs loose focus
            elem.hide();
    }, 0);
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NxfmW/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var timeoutID;

    jQuery(":input").focus(function () {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    }).focusout(function () {
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery("#baz").hide();
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: In my experience, when doing this, the timeout is in the 50/200 range.

Comment: Don't believe it matters. The important point is to execute the code after the next element has received the focus and not immediately when none of the element would have focus. However, it won't hurt to put some more timeout.

Comment: Since it's a race condition and that's what the timeout is for, my experience has taught me that at least 50 and up to 200/250 give the same visual result, while dealing with less powerful or other situations.

Comment: Also, I like namuol's tip about `.hide()` instead of `.css('display','none')`.

Comment: I wish I could test this in FF3, but FF4 the focusout isn't being triggered by keyboard tabbing.  Only if the initial input box was clicked on.  It does, however, work in Chrome.

Comment: You can download a FirefoxPortable for FF3 and run it separately, I believe.

Comment: @amit_g: please see my answer, amend yours, and I'll give you credit for this

Comment: @JaredFarrish: There is no such thing as a race condition in pure JavaScript, or if you want, there was not at the time of publishing your comment. It is possible to create a race condition in JavaScript provided that the web interface is written in HTML5 and that the JavaScript code is using Web Workers API. If it is not using Web Workers, the execution of JavaScript code is strictly serialized. https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/06/17/no-there-are-no-race-conditions-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I think amit_g's solution was almost there.  I vaguely remember that I've went about this in two ways:

1. compare the inputs to the `activeElement` (the method showed above)
2. setting/clearing a "focus" class on the element for the respective events

I think both methods required using `setTimeout`, since Firefox has a delayed trigger, which we need to force.  While I've heard FF is adhering to standards here, I personally think that standard needs to be amended.

---

So in addition to adding the timed function call, it also needed to be cleared if the other "acceptable" element gained focus.  The following is not production code but it does show it does serve as an example:

#### [Example Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/mvW3B/2/)

#### [Example Solution (Even Better)](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/mvW3B/4/) - set `$debug` to `false`

#### [Example Solution (Localized Blocks)](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/NxfmW/2/) - removed debugging clutter

Comment: Updated. In this check of ActiveElement is not needed. Also the elem needs to be saved because in timer $(this) is not going to be the element of interest.

Comment: You're absolutely right about that, I think I wanted to leave activeElement in case I wanted to compare to other elements outside of that block, which may/may not have been an input, but right, the premature conditional return, is unnecessary +1

Comment: @amit_g: That said, if you want to localize this to the div block, you'll still need to hold the previous object, so you can compare to the siblings ([See here](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/NxfmW/2/))